# Change of Limits of Integration in $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$ Using Polar Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, gamma-function

Solving

$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx$$
$$ \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=2\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$$

$$\begin{align}
{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2} = 4\left(\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx\right) \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y^2}dy\right) \\
=4\int_{0}^\infty\left(\int_{0}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)} dx\right)dy \end{align}\\$$

Changing to polar coordinates: $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and  $dx\,dy=r\,d\theta\,dr$

$$
\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}rdrd\theta \\
=4\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}rdr= \pi
$$
$$
\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}
$$

The question is, why is the limits of integration $0\to\frac{\pi}{2}$
Instead of $0\to2\pi$?

How is the $\theta$ bounded in such a way?

Comment: Because the region being integrated over (in cartesian coordinates) is the set $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x>0,y>0\}$, not $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @projectilemotion is $x,y>0$ the consequence of the gamma function itself ?

Comment: $- \infty \leq x \leq \infty, -\infty \leq y \leq \infty$ in cartesian coordinates maps to

$0 \leq r \leq \infty, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ in polar coordinates with $x = r \cos\theta, y = r \sin\theta$.

Comment: Here $0 \leq x \leq \infty, 0 \leq y \leq \infty$, which is first quadrant and hence $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @mkcpz I'm not quite sure what you mean by that, what I'm referring to is the integral $$4\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-(x^2+y^2)}~dx~dy$$ Here the $x$ and $y$ variables are being integrated over all $x,y>0$.

Comment: @projectilemotion Oh then can you please tell me why $x,y$ is integrated from $0\to \infty$ only (the first quadrant)? Thank you

Comment: @mkcpz Do you understand all the steps before *"Changing to polar coordinates..."*? If so, just look at the last integral before that sentence very carefully, and look at the set of values that $x$ is being integrated over and the set of values that $y$ is being integrated over.

Comment: @projectilemotion OH,  because of the square root that I neglected due to shortcuts? Oh my god Im so bad at this

Comment: @mkcpz No, it has nothing to do with that. Here's perhaps a more concrete example. Consider the double integral $$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-3}^3 f(x,y)~dx~dy.$$ Here we are integrating $f$ over a rectangle (with length $6$ over the $x$ axis and $2$ over the $y$ axis) $[-3,3]\times [-1,1]$. Now look back at the integral I was referring to and you should see that you are integrating over the first quadrant.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me suggest formal answer to question: having set $\mathbb{R^2}=\{(x,y)\colon x \in \mathbb{R} \land y \in \mathbb{R}\}=\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ with [Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) we can consider [Polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) in which for each pair $(x,y)$ we would like to put in accordance distance $r$ from reference point and angle $\theta$ from reference direction. For any point besides $(0,0)$ this immediately gives formulas:
$$x = r \cos \theta \\
y = r \sin \theta$$
but difficulties only starts here, because we obtain infinite possible solutions $(r,\theta)$ for one $(x,y)$. Accepted solution is to consider separately case $(0,0)$ and for other pairs having restrictions on $(r,\theta)$ taking any half-open $2\pi$ length interval for $\theta$, for example $[0,2\pi)$, and $r > 0$.

De facto, we have one $\mathbb{R^2}_{(x,y)}$ mapped on many its instances on $\mathbb{R^2}_{(r,\theta)}$, but we choose only one to obtain uniqueness.

So, when you consider changing to polar coordinates, from scratch, you consider some restrictions as, for example, $(r,\theta) \in (0, +\infty)\times [0,2\pi)$ .

In your case, to obtain image of set from $\mathbb{R^2}_{(x,y)}$ in $\mathbb{R^2}_{(r,\theta)}$ we formally solve equations from above in existing restriction : having 1-st quadrant $\{(x,y)\colon x>0 \land y>0\}$ on $\mathbb{R^2}_{(x,y)}$  we obtain
$$x=r \cos \theta > 0 \\
y=r \sin \theta > 0$$
which gives no restriction on $r$ and $\theta \in \left[ 0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ i.e. $\left\lbrace(r,\theta)\colon r>0 \land 0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2}\right\rbrace$ on $\mathbb{R^2}_{(r,\theta)}$.

Comment: Oh, so the image set when using polar coordinates in the given integral corresponds to the "first quadrant" of a circle? Ok

Comment: Circle goes to rectangle, first quadrant to rectangular endless half-strip.